# Excel find cells from range where search value is within the cell

Tags: excel

Once again I'm struggling to find my answer on Google, but I'm sure it must exist.  Sorry if I come across as a novice: I am when it comes to Excel it seems!

What I'd like to be able to do is tell it to search a range, then find cells within that range that contain text that is in my search function.  I don't need any kind of result from it other than either TRUE or >1 (if it matches, obviously).

In this instance I'm searching a RANGE that is comprised of years, one year in each cell, and trying to find cells in that range that contain a year from a list of years that are all in one cell.

Basically I'm wanting to use a function similar to the Search function I think.

```
=SEARCH(text to find, find within text)
```

However, I'd like it to do the opposite and find cells that contain some of the text within the source cell:

```
=SEARCH(find within text, text to find)
```

Or, more specifically

```
=SEARCH("2001,2002,2003,2004,2005", "2003")
```

Is this possible without the use of a Macro?  I'd prefer to avoid it if at all possible.  All cells in question are formatted as Text.

I have been experimenting with COUNTIF, but again it works in the reverse of what I need.

Sorry if this question is unclear.
Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Joe

Comment: I just read this back through, it seems like gibberish sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way, but if I'm understanding correctly, you could try `SUM` in combination with an array formula (enter with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(A1:E1,G1),0))>0, "FOUND", "NOT FOUND")
```

Here, `A1:E1` contained the individual years and `G1` contained the single cell of years. This  runs `FIND` on each cell in the range, returning a position if it finds a match in the target cell and returning 0 if not (`IFERROR` is a 2007 function - if you don't have Excel 2007, we can rewrite). You then sum the results of the `FIND` function and if it is greater than 0, it means you found a match somewhere.

[image]

Comment: nice answer! And again this shows how strange the array formula in excel works...

Comment: @K_B Thanks - arrays definitely make things interesting :)

Comment: You could save a function by using COUNT, i.e. `=IF(COUNT(FIND(A1:E1,G1)),"Found","Not Found")` - that still need's "array entry" - or use my old friend LOOKUP for a non-array version `=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(A1:E1,G1))),"Not Found","Found")`

Comment: @barryhoudini Ah very cool - I didn't know that `COUNT` properly handled `N/A#` values - thanks yet again for teaching me something new :) Awesome `LOOKUP` as well.

Comment: @barryhoudini: your lookup option is excellent. Worked great as I needed to try and avoid arrays.